# Need to remove files older then 90 days with an exception of last day of the month

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, python

Need help in deleting files from unix directory which are older then 90 days, but need to retain files which belongs to end of the month date. (ex: 28th Feb 2022, 31th march, 30th April )
for Ex:

I have files in directory as:
/usr/home :

1. ABC.txt.20220529  2022-05-30
2. ABC.txt.20220530  2022-05-31
3. ABC.txt.20220531  2022-06-01
4. ABC.txt.20220601  2022-06-02

and if I run my script on the 91st day from 1st June,
it should delete 1 and should not delete 2/3/4
need a script either in shell script or python.

Comment: How are you working with the date of each file?  Are you considering the `access date`, `change date` or `birth/created date`? Or are you working directly with the filenames?

Comment: In case you are working with the filenames, what is the correct format of these one? `ABC.txt.20220529 2022-05-30` or `ABC.txt.20220529`?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that's the date at the end of the file name you want to consider  (the `20220531` in `ABC.txt.20220531`), in `zsh`, you could do:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/datetime
day=86400
strftime -s range '<19700101-%Y%m%d>' $(( EPOCHSECONDS - 91 * day ))
not_last() {
  local t
  TZ=UTC0 strftime -rs t %Y%m%d $REPLY:e &&
    TZ=UTC0 strftime -s t %d $(( t + day )) &&
    (( t != 1 ))
}
echo rm -f -- **/*.txt.$~range(-.+not_last)
```

If it's the last modification time:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/datetime
zmodload zsh/stat
day=86400
not_last() {
  local t
  stat -A t +mtime -- $REPLY &&
    strftime -s t %d $(( t + day )) &&
    (( t != 1 ))
}
echo rm -f -- **/*.txt.*(-.m+90+not_last)
```

Bearing in mind that if there was a DST change on the first or last day of the month, there's a tiny chance it could throw off the next day calculation.

The type and mtime of the file is considered *after* symlink resolution. If you want to ignore symlinks, remove the `-` glob qualifier. Add the `D` qualifier to also consider hidden files. Remove the `**/` if you don't want to consider files in subdirectories.

Remove the `echo` (dry-run) if happy with the result.

Note that `m+90`, like `find`'s `-mtime +90` selects files that are 91 day old or older, change to `m+89` for files that are 90 day old or older.

Comment: Liked this answer! It's very useful for `zsh` shells. I would like if you can provide an example by using `GNU date` according to your answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223546/414186.
Or it's harder implementing in that way perhaps?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, there's nothing stopping you calling `zsh` from other shells. Actually, those in my answer are written as standalone scripts which you can call from any shell or non-shell.

Comment: That's right, if the user has `zsh` installed then they won't have problems. On MacOS and some Linux distros have `zsh` as the default shell.

Answer (score 2):

Last day of the month are the ones ending in 0131, 0331, 0430... 1231 and 0229 for bissextile years and 0228 on other years.

With GNU `date` and a shell with support for `zsh`-style `{x..y}` brace expansion, you can get the list of the last day in February from 1970 to 2099 for instance with:

```
printf '%s\n' {1970..2099}'-03-01 -1 day' | date -uf- +%Y%m%d
```

So you could construct an extended regexp that matches those dates with:

```
regexp=$(
  {
    printf '%s\n' {0{1,3,5,7,8},10,12}31 {04,06,09,11}30
    printf '%s\n' {1970..2099}'-03-01 -1 day' | date -uf- '+%Y%m%d'
  } | paste -sd '|' -
)
```

So with GNU `date` and an `awk` implementation that supports NUL as `R`ecord `S`eparator:

```bash
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*.txt.[0-9]*' -print0 |
  LC_ALL=C awk -F. -v 'RS=\0' \
                   -v 'ORS=\0' \
                   -v regexp="($regexp)\$" \
                   -v cutoff="$(date -d '90 days ago' +%Y%m%d)" '
    /txt\.[0-9]{8}$/ && $NF < cutoff && $NF !~ regexp' |
  xargs -r0 echo rm -f
```

Or to match on the last modification time of the files as opposed to the date at the end of their name, with the GNU implementation of `find`:

```bash
LC_ALL=C find . -regextype posix-extended \
                -regex '.*\.txt\.[0-9]{8}' \
                -mtime +90 \
                -printf '%TY%Tm%Td-%p\0' |
  LC_ALL=C awk -v 'RS=\0' \
               -v 'ORS=\0' \
               -v regexp="^[0-9]*($regexp)-" '
    $0 !~ regexp {print substr($0, 10)}' |
  xargs -r0 echo rm -f
```

You could use the same approach to construct a zsh glob pattern that matches those.

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/datetime
set -o extendedglob
day=86400

start=19700101
strftime -s end %Y%m%d $(( EPOCHSECONDS - 91 * day ))
range="<$start-$end>"

list=({0{1,3,5,7,8},10,12}31 {04,06,09,11}30)

for ((y = $start[1,4]; y <= $end[1,4]; y++)) {
  TZ=UTC0 strftime -rs t %Y%m%d ${y}0301 &&
    TZ=UTC0 strftime -s d %Y%m%d $(( t - day )) &&
    list+=($d)
}
endofmonth="*(${(j[|])list})"

echo rm -f -- **/*.txt.($~range~$~endofmonth)
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the other answers, but I have a simpler solution.
Also, the original question assumes that the last-of-month (date) file is always there. But we all know that you don't always have the snapshot from the last of the month.

I'm modifying the problem a bit and answering that;

1. keep last file for each month that is there, not necessarily the 31st, 30th, 28th
2. keep files that are 0-90 days old
3. remove files older than 90 days, but not if they are the last for a month.

I don't care about the list of files in the example, because the approach is important. You can adjust the input if you understand the approach.

Given a random list of days:

```
function dates() { echo 2022-12-{06..12}  2022-{01,03,05}-{00..31} 2022-02-{00..28} 2022-{04,06}-{01..30}   2022-12-{01..06} 2022-10-{01..03}| tr ' ' \\n;  }
```

In this list all days are present in months 1-6, only 12 days are listed in December and only 3 days in October.

To find the last days *present* in this list for each month, we will sort the list in ascending order and then remember every "oldest" date for each month.  This gives the *last of month*.

```
$ dates | sort \
  | awk -F- '{ lom[$1$2]=$1"-"$2"-"$3 } END { for (i in lom) { print lom[i]} }' \
  | tee /tmp/lom  
2022-01-31
2022-02-28
2022-03-31
2022-04-30
2022-05-31
2022-06-30
2022-10-03
2022-12-12
```

I don't care about the calendar dates in a real-life IT problem. I care about the files that are actually there. If the 12th is the last snapshot for December and there is no 31st, because the system was broken that day, then I want to keep the 12th.

So now we know what *not to delete*. The other part is older than 90 days:

```
dates | awk -v cutoff=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d 'today -90 days') \
            '{ if ($1 < cutoff) { print $1 } }'  \
      | grep -v -f /tmp/lom
```

This will print dates that are over 90 days old and exclude the *last of moth* entries. Short and sweet. Perfect.

As the guru pointed out, the whole thing above can be done in one line. wow!

```
dates | sort -r | awk -v cutoff=$(date +%F -d '-90 days') -F- '$0 < cutoff && seen[$1$2]++'
```

The generated list of dates to purge contains this:

```
2022-01-00  2022-03-11  2022-05-22  2022-04-05
2022-01-01  2022-03-12  2022-05-23  2022-04-06
2022-01-02  2022-03-13  2022-05-24  2022-04-07
2022-01-03  2022-03-14  2022-05-25  2022-04-08
2022-01-04  2022-03-15  2022-05-26  2022-04-09
2022-01-05  2022-03-16  2022-05-27  2022-04-10
2022-01-06  2022-03-17  2022-05-28  2022-04-11
2022-01-07  2022-03-18  2022-05-29  2022-04-12
2022-01-08  2022-03-19  2022-05-30  2022-04-13
2022-01-09  2022-03-20  2022-02-00  2022-04-14
2022-01-10  2022-03-21  2022-02-01  2022-04-15
2022-01-11  2022-03-22  2022-02-02  2022-04-16
2022-01-12  2022-03-23  2022-02-03  2022-04-17
2022-01-13  2022-03-24  2022-02-04  2022-04-18
2022-01-14  2022-03-25  2022-02-05  2022-04-19
2022-01-15  2022-03-26  2022-02-06  2022-04-20
2022-01-16  2022-03-27  2022-02-07  2022-04-21
2022-01-17  2022-03-28  2022-02-08  2022-04-22
2022-01-18  2022-03-29  2022-02-09  2022-04-23
2022-01-19  2022-03-30  2022-02-10  2022-04-24
2022-01-20  2022-05-00  2022-02-11  2022-04-25
2022-01-21  2022-05-01  2022-02-12  2022-04-26
2022-01-22  2022-05-02  2022-02-13  2022-04-27
2022-01-23  2022-05-03  2022-02-14  2022-04-28
2022-01-24  2022-05-04  2022-02-15  2022-04-29
2022-01-25  2022-05-05  2022-02-16  2022-06-00
2022-01-26  2022-05-06  2022-02-17  2022-06-01
2022-01-27  2022-05-07  2022-02-18  2022-06-02
2022-01-28  2022-05-08  2022-02-19  2022-06-03
2022-01-29  2022-05-09  2022-02-20  2022-06-04
2022-01-30  2022-05-10  2022-02-21  2022-06-05
2022-03-00  2022-05-11  2022-02-22  2022-06-06
2022-03-01  2022-05-12  2022-02-23  2022-06-07
2022-03-02  2022-05-13  2022-02-24  2022-06-08
2022-03-03  2022-05-14  2022-02-25  2022-06-09
2022-03-04  2022-05-15  2022-02-26  2022-06-10
2022-03-05  2022-05-16  2022-02-27  2022-06-11
2022-03-06  2022-05-17  2022-04-00  2022-06-12
2022-03-07  2022-05-18  2022-04-01  2022-06-13
2022-03-08  2022-05-19  2022-04-02  2022-06-14
2022-03-09  2022-05-20  2022-04-03  2022-06-15
2022-03-10  2022-05-21  2022-04-04  2022-06-16
```

Comment: See `dates | sort -r | sort -t- -uk1,2` to get the latest date  for each month and `comm` to do list subtractions (though the whole thing could be done with `dates | sort -r | awk -F- '$0 < cutoff && seen[$1$2]++'`)

Comment: Note that `%Y-%m-%d` can also be written `%F` (see also `date --iso-8601`)